# Consolidating array and adding amounts of similar objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that contain a date and an amount (among other things).

There is an object for each date with a specific amount, but there can also be multiple objects for the same date containing different amounts.

I'd like to consolidate the objects so I only have one object in the array for each date ... and have the amount corresponding to that date be the total sum of all previous amounts in those objects.

Examples will probably help here:

**What my array looks like now:**

```
[
    {
        date: "2019-1-1", // this is a dupe date
        amount: 20,
        ...
    },
    {
        date: "2019-1-1", // this is a dupe date
        amount: 40,
        ...
    },
    {
        date: "2019-1-2",
        amount: 40,
        ...
    },
    {
        date: "2019-1-3",
        amount: 40,
        ...
    }
]
```

**What I would like my array to look like:**

```
[
    {
        date: "2019-1-1", // this is now a unique date
        amount: 60,       // and the amount was totaled
        ...
    },
    {
        date: "2019-1-2",
        amount: 40,
        ...
    },
    {
        date: "2019-1-3",
        amount: 40,
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: Please include the code you've written

Comment: @AluanHaddad Is there a rule I don't see that requires code in questions? I don't see it. I'm asking how to do it, not why my code isn't working.

Comment: SO is to help you fix issues with code you have written, not write code for you. Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RobG Thanks, I'll take that into consideration for my next question on here. I do want to point out on that page it does not really state that though: "Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some." Maybe that page needs an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.reduce` to reduce an array into an object (or into anything else) by iterating over its properties. You just need to test to see if an object with a matching `date` already exists in the accumulator first:

```js
const input = [
  {
    date: "2019-1-1", // this is a dupe date
    amount: 20,
    foo: 'bar',
  },
  {
    date: "2019-1-1", // this is a dupe date
    amount: 40,
    foo: 'bar',
  },
  {
    date: "2019-1-2",
    amount: 40,
    foo: 'bar',
  },
  {
    date: "2019-1-3",
    amount: 40,
    foo: 'bar',
  }
];
const output = input.reduce((accum, item) => {
  const { date, amount } = item;
  const foundObj = accum.find(({ date: findDate }) => findDate === date);
  if (foundObj) {
    foundObj.amount += amount;
    return accum;
  }
  accum.push(item);
  return accum;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do as follows;

```js
var data = [ { date: "2019-1-1", // this is a dupe date
               amount: 20},
             { date: "2019-1-1", // this is a dupe date
               amount: 40},
             { date: "2019-1-2",
               amount: 40},
             { date: "2019-1-3",
               amount: 40}
           ],
   result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,d) => r[d.date] ? (r[d.date].amount += d.amount, r)
                                                         : (r[d.date] = d, r), {}));
console.log(result);
```

Regarding a comment i guess i have to explain this a little for those who may not be familiar with some ES6 functionalities.

[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is a Object method which returns all own property values in an array.

So we are reducing our objects into an hash object of which we collect the properties by `Object.values()` later. While reducing we check if the currently examined object's `date` value exists as key in our map. If not we create that key and insert the examined object at that key position, if yes then we increment the previously inserted objects `amount` property by the value of currently examined `objects` amount value.

If you don't want to mutate the original data then please change `r[d.date] = d` into `r[d.date] = Object.assign({},d)`.

Comment: Bad idea, that mutates the original objects.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You may be right. In this case i suppose it might be better to change `r[d.date] = d` into `r[d.date] = Object.assign({},d)`.

Comment: Code only answers are helpful, a good answer should include an explanation of how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to create an object with the dates as the key, then you can iterate over the array and create a new date property if it doesn't exist or increase the amount if it does, then convert it back into an array:

```
const items = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (!acc[curr.date]) {  // basically creating a property with the date as the key and the value is the current object
        acc[curr.date] = { ...curr };
    } else {    // if it exists already, then just increment the amount
        acc[curr.date].amount += curr.amount;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});

const newArray = Object.values(items);  // grab all the values from the object above
```

Comment: Another issue is that your method mutates the original objects.

Comment: I also change the variable name if that's what you were referring to.

Comment: ah, nvm i see what you're saying

Comment: It still references the original object in memory; the original object gets mutated, regardless of the variable name used to refer to it.